# Al subir los datos de mi galeria de imagenes a MySQL los datos ingresados se representan como "NULL"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp

```
<?php  //este es el php donde conecto la seccion de subir imagenes a la DB

    require './funciones.php';
    $conexion = conexion('galeria','root','');

    if (!$conexion) {    
        header ('Location: error.php');
    }

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_FILES)) {      // 
        print_r($_FILES);

        $check = getimagesize($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name']);

        if ($check !== false) {         
            $carpeta_destino = 'fotos/';        
            $archivo_subido = $carpeta_destino . $_FILES['foto']['name'];            
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'], $archivo_subido);

            $statement = $conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO FOTOS(TITULO, IMAGEN, DESCRIPCION)VALUES(:TITULO, :IMAGEN, :DESCRIPCION)');

            $statement->execute(array(':TITULO' => $_POST['TITULO'],':IMAGEN' =>$_FILES['FOTO']['NAME'],':DESCRIPCION'=>$_POST['DESCRIPCION']));

            header('Location: index.php');    }else{
            $error="No es una imagen o el archivo es muy pesado";    
        } 
    }    
     require_once 'views/subir.view.php';

  ?>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BisAU.png

Comment: el nombre de la tabla es `fotos` con minuscula y tu consulta tiene `FOTOS` con mayuscula, prueba corregirlo, si no es eso probablemente sea algo de configuracion de coneccion con la base de datos

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Los valores en la base de datos aparecen NULL es por el hecho de que no estan recibiendo ningun valor para que este sea guardado.

En esta linea esta llamando las variables,  pero estas no tienen ningun valor

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO FOTOS(TITULO, IMAGEN, DESCRIPCION)VALUES(:TITULO, :IMAGEN, :DESCRIPCION)');
```

En esta linea se cambiaron las variables por los valores que necesitas.

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO FOTOS(TITULO, IMAGEN, DESCRIPCION)VALUES($_POST['TITULO'], $_FILES['FOTO']['NAME'], $_POST['DESCRIPCION'])");
```

Comment: Tu respuesta no es correcta, el OP esta haciendo correctamente la prevención de SQLInjection, la repuesta que tu le has dado no contribuye con el objetivo y le estas quitando toda la seguridad.